# Same website on two dfferent machine on local network

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, load-balancing, website

I have a website in a local network on two different machines.
The machines have IP addresses 192.168.2.2 and 192.168.2.3.
I have a firewall that should execute server load balancing when one of two machines becomes busy. 
In this scenario, I don't have a domain name, but when I want to connect to this web site I always ask for 192.168.2.2 in my browser. Then If this machine can't respond, the firewall should send the request to 192.168.2.3.
So my question is, how can I configure Apache on 192.168.2.3 to answer request even if they come with 192.168.2.2 name?
Any help would be apreciated

Comment: If you have only one virtual host on each server (or none) then you don't need to do anything, it will just work. You should just make sure the setup (other than the bind IP) is the same on both servers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on the same local network then firewall is not involved in comunication with web server an you. You need load balancer. For example nginx. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html